# "at least" vs. "at the least"

Tags: differences, phrase-usage

Could somebody please elaborate on the difference(s) between "at least" and "at the least"? Could the wrong usage potentially lead to misunderstanding or would it just be improper?

Comment: I see no significant difference that would lead to a misunderstanding. The "the" acts as an intensifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can find no grammatical ruling for the need to use ***'very'*** with ***'least'***.
I believe it is simply a personal choice and possibly implies emphasis.
For example;
[Exasperated parent to child] *"Can you at the very least go and tidy your room"* implies to the reader more frustration than simply 
*"Can you at least go and tidy your room"*.
So I would suggest that you always use ***'at least'*** unless you wish to add emphasis.
HTH

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I did not have problem with `very`, but instead the point of the question was on using `the` before least. However, your answer made me delete `very` from the question to make sure that nobody else would focus on that.

Comment: Well now I'm afraid neither your question nor my answer make any sense. _'at the least'_ is meaningless.

Comment: With all due respect, there are separate entries for them in different dictionaries with the word `very` in parenthesis for the second one

Comment: Yes you are correct, as I've just noticed on OED site, they give the following example; _'stay ten days at the least'_. I still claim that _'at least'_ is sufficient in all cases unless emphasis is required.

Answer (score 0):

If the focus is on "the least" vs just "least", then the answer is elsewhere. It's a beautifully crafted accepted answer.

See: [Superlatives with "the"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30272/superlatives-with-the)